# Xamarin - Type not found in xmlns clr-namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making a Xamarin Forms app, the solution is called `RESTTest`, my shared project is called `RestApp`.

In my shared project I have a folder called `ViewModels`, which contains a class called `MainViewModel.cs`

I have a page called `MainPage.xaml` which has a code-behind called `MainPage.xaml.cs`. In my XAML I am trying to include my Viewmodels folder like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RestApp"
             x:Class="RestApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:RestApp.ViewModels;assembly=RestApp">
```

But when I add binding to my page like this:

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
         <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

I am getting an unhandled exception:

```
Type ViewModels:MainViewModel not found in xmlns clr-namespace:RestApp.ViewModels;assembly=RestApp
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the ";assembly=RestApp" in the namespace, and setting the linker behaviour to "Link SDK Assemblies Only" worked for me and solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have Linker optimizations that trim unused code.

Note that deserialization into a type may not be detectable by the linker as a type use.

In the properties of your project find the "Linker Behavior" option under "iOS Build" or "Android Build", and set it to either "Link SDK assemblies only" or "Don’t Link". You'll need to clean+rebuild your whole solution for the change to take effect.

Comment: Hi Sten, In my `Linking` in `Android Options` it is currently set to `None` is that correct, I don't see a "Don't Link" option

Comment: @BarneyChambers yes, that's what it should be. If it still doesn't find it then in your main method in the android app where Xamarin.Froms.Init is called add 'object o = typeof(ViewModels.MainViewModel)' to make sure the type can be reached compile-time

Comment: I tried every linking permutation and unfortunately this didn't solve my problem

Comment: I added the hardcoded reference but am still seeing the error

Comment: check that 1. Action set on the file is Compile and 2. your shared project is referenced in your main project. 3. Is your assembly name RestApp? If you used PCL it would be but because it is shared project it actually may be RestApp.Android (not sure)?

Comment: Try to remove the ;assembly=RestApp in the namespace

Comment: This worked for me.  Was adding an OnScreenSize to parody OnPlatform and it just couldn't find it when it built.  Wasted hours on this...  I've added an init method to my library so it references all my xaml only classes.  Suddenly it builds.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cvt="clr-namespace:XamarinTest.UI.Resources.Converts;assembly=XamarinTest.UI">
    <cvt:DoubleToImageConverter x:Key="CVT_DoubleToImage"/>
    <cvt:MediaTypeToImageConverter x:Key="CVT_MediaTypeToImage"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my app, I add the `assembly=XamarinTest.UI` solved the problem. I think the dev team may removed the `assembly=xxxx` section in Xamarin Forms 5.0.